# save upload img in php session

Tags: php, session, file-upload

so i have build a 3 step form, on step 1 there is a upload file input at the end of step one when the step one is validated i call:

```
$_SESSION['img']=array();
$_SESSION['img']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$_SESSION['img']['name']=$_FILES['file']['name'];

_crop("data/", $_SESSION['img']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['img']['name'] , 83, 83);
```

with `_crop` being the function that resize my image, so here everything works the img is uploaded to the data/  dir and resize, but if i call the function _crop at the third step of my form the img wont be uploaded even if

```
$_SESSION['img']['tmp_name']=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$_SESSION['img']['name']=$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

are still visible on step 3 of the form.

Comment: try printing `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` or `$_FILES['file']['name'];` on step 3, and i guess you will get to now what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded files are temporary, and deleted just after request is completed, you should move temporary file to some directory, using [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Read Carefully: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php

File is moved, not copied from the temporary directory

Comment: hard with the English, do not have time to write :(